# JavaFX 11 Deployment Failure: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:fileset

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

I am trying to deploy my project but I keep receiving the following errors, what should I do ? Also, I have java 11 but I can only select project language levels up to 10 in IntelliJ, yet I can use "var" syntax and run it. IntelliJ info:

> **EDIT:** Apparently intellij IDEA 1.x does not support java 11 I have downloaded the recent version and currently trying to redo the whole
> process
>
> **FINAL EDIT: I have solved the problem by using java 8 on intelliJ IDEA 3.x and followed this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf7bFiPOKvc). Thank you [hce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9744335/hce)!**

[image: idea]

> Information:Java FX Packager: [C:/Program
> Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2\bin\java, -Dant.home=D:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA
> 2018.1.5\lib\ant, -classpath, D:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5\lib\ant/lib/ant.jar;D:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5\lib\ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/lib/ant-javafx.jar;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar,
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher, -f,
> C:\Users\HP.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\compile-server\luckypick-m_8a6db982_temp_\build.xml]
> Information:Java FX Packager: Buildfile:
> C:\Users\HP.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\compile-server\luckypick-m_8a6db982_temp_\build.xml
> Information:Java FX Packager:   [taskdef] Could not load definitions
> from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be
> found. Information:Java FX Packager:  Information:Java FX Packager:
> build artifact: Information:27.01.2019 15:09 - Compilation completed
> with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 8 s 226 ms Error:Java FX Packager:
> BUILD FAILED
> C:\Users\HP.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\compile-server\luckypick-m_8a6db982_temp_\build.xml:3:
> Problem: failed to create task or type
> javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:fileset Cause: The name is undefined.
> Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any custom tasks/types
> have been declared. Action: Check that any /
> declarations have taken place. No types or tasks have been defined in
> this namespace yet Total time: 0 seconds Error:Java FX Packager:
> fx:deploy task has failed.

Here is how my project directory looks and which files it has.

[image: directory]

Here's luckypick.properties

```
path.variable.kotl\u0131n_bundled=D\:\\Programs\\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5\\plugins\\Kotlin\\kotlinc
path.variable.maven_repos\u0131tory=C\:\\Users\\HP\\.m2\\repository
jdk.home.11=C\:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2
idea.home=D\:/Programs/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5
javafx.home=C\:/Users/HP/Documents/javafx-sdk-11.0.2
javac2.instrumentation.includeJavaRuntime=false
```

Here's luckypick.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="luckypick" default="all">


    <property file="luckypick.properties"/>
    <!-- Uncomment the following property if no tests compilation is needed -->
    <!--
    <property name="skip.tests" value="true"/>
     -->

    <!-- Compiler options -->

    <property name="compiler.debug" value="on"/>
    <property name="compiler.generate.no.warnings" value="off"/>
    <property name="compiler.args" value=""/>
    <property name="compiler.max.memory" value="700m"/>
    <patternset id="ignored.files">
        <exclude name="**/*.hprof/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.pyc/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.pyo/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.rbc/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.yarb/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/*~/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/.DS_Store/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/.git/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/.hg/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/.svn/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/CVS/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/__pycache__/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/_svn/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/vssver.scc/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/vssver2.scc/**"/>
    </patternset>
    <patternset id="library.patterns">
        <include name="*.egg"/>
        <include name="*.jar"/>
        <include name="*.ear"/>
        <include name="*.swc"/>
        <include name="*.war"/>
        <include name="*.zip"/>
        <include name="*.ane"/>
    </patternset>
    <patternset id="compiler.resources">
        <exclude name="**/?*.java"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.form"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.class"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.groovy"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.scala"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.flex"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.kt"/>
        <exclude name="**/?*.clj"/>
    </patternset>

    <!-- JDK definitions -->

    <property name="jdk.bin.11" value="${jdk.home.11}/bin"/>
    <path id="jdk.classpath.11">
        <fileset dir="${jdk.home.11}">
            <include name="/legal/java.base"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.compiler"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.datatransfer"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.desktop"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.instrument"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.logging"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.management"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.management.rmi"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.naming"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.net.http"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.prefs"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.rmi"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.scripting"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.se"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.security.jgss"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.security.sasl"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.smartcardio"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.sql"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.sql.rowset"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.transaction.xa"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.xml"/>
            <include name="/legal/java.xml.crypto"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.accessibility"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.aot"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.attach"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.charsets"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.compiler"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.crypto.cryptoki"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.crypto.ec"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.crypto.mscapi"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.dynalink"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.editpad"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.hotspot.agent"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.httpserver"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.ed"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.jvmstat"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.le"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.opt"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.vm.ci"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.vm.compiler"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jartool"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.javadoc"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jcmd"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jconsole"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jdeps"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jdi"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jdwp.agent"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jfr"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jlink"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jshell"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jsobject"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.jstatd"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.localedata"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.management"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.management.agent"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.management.jfr"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.naming.dns"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.naming.rmi"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.net"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.pack"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.rmic"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.scripting.nashorn"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.sctp"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.security.auth"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.security.jgss"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.unsupported"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.unsupported.desktop"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.xml.dom"/>
            <include name="/legal/jdk.zipfs"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <property name="project.jdk.home" value="${jdk.home.11}"/>
    <property name="project.jdk.bin" value="${jdk.bin.11}"/>
    <property name="project.jdk.classpath" value="jdk.classpath.11"/>


    <!-- Project Libraries -->

    <path id="library.javafx-swt.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx-swt.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.base.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.controls.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.fxml.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.graphics.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.media.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.swing.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${javafx.home}/lib/javafx.web.jar"/>
    </path>


    <!-- Global Libraries -->
    <!-- Register Custom Compiler Taskdefs -->
    <property name="javac2.home" value="${idea.home}/lib"/>
    <path id="javac2.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${javac2.home}">
            <include name="javac2.jar"/>
            <include name="jdom.jar"/>
            <include name="asm-all*.jar"/>
            <include name="jgoodies-forms.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="register.custom.compilers">
        <taskdef name="javac2" classname="com.intellij.ant.Javac2" classpathref="javac2.classpath"/>
        <taskdef name="instrumentIdeaExtensions" classname="com.intellij.ant.InstrumentIdeaExtensions"
                 classpathref="javac2.classpath"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Modules -->


    <!-- Module LuckyPick -->

    <dirname property="module.luckypick.basedir" file="${ant.file}"/>


    <property name="module.jdk.home.luckypick" value="${project.jdk.home}"/>
    <property name="module.jdk.bin.luckypick" value="${project.jdk.bin}"/>
    <property name="module.jdk.classpath.luckypick" value="${project.jdk.classpath}"/>

    <property name="compiler.args.luckypick" value="-encoding UTF-8 -source 10 -target 10 ${compiler.args}"/>

    <property name="luckypick.output.dir" value="${module.luckypick.basedir}/out/production/LuckyPick"/>
    <property name="luckypick.testoutput.dir" value="${module.luckypick.basedir}/out/test/LuckyPick"/>

    <path id="luckypick.module.bootclasspath">
        <!-- Paths to be included in compilation bootclasspath -->
    </path>

    <path id="luckypick.module.production.classpath">
        <path refid="${module.jdk.classpath.luckypick}"/>
        <path refid="library.javafx-swt.classpath"/>
    </path>

    <path id="luckypick.runtime.production.module.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${luckypick.output.dir}"/>
        <path refid="library.javafx-swt.classpath"/>
    </path>

    <path id="luckypick.module.classpath">
        <path refid="${module.jdk.classpath.luckypick}"/>
        <pathelement location="${luckypick.output.dir}"/>
        <path refid="library.javafx-swt.classpath"/>
    </path>

    <path id="luckypick.runtime.module.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${luckypick.testoutput.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${luckypick.output.dir}"/>
        <path refid="library.javafx-swt.classpath"/>
    </path>


    <patternset id="excluded.from.module.luckypick">
        <patternset refid="ignored.files"/>
    </patternset>

    <patternset id="excluded.from.compilation.luckypick">
        <patternset refid="excluded.from.module.luckypick"/>
    </patternset>

    <path id="luckypick.module.sourcepath">
        <dirset dir="${module.luckypick.basedir}">
            <include name="src"/>
            <include name="res"/>
        </dirset>
    </path>


    <target name="compile.module.luckypick" depends="compile.module.luckypick.production,compile.module.luckypick.tests"
            description="Compile module LuckyPick"/>

    <target name="compile.module.luckypick.production" depends="register.custom.compilers"
            description="Compile module LuckyPick; production classes">
        <mkdir dir="${luckypick.output.dir}"/>
        <javac2 destdir="${luckypick.output.dir}" debug="${compiler.debug}" nowarn="${compiler.generate.no.warnings}"
                memorymaximumsize="${compiler.max.memory}" fork="true" executable="${module.jdk.bin.luckypick}/javac">
            <compilerarg line="${compiler.args.luckypick}"/>
            <bootclasspath refid="luckypick.module.bootclasspath"/>
            <classpath refid="luckypick.module.production.classpath"/>
            <src refid="luckypick.module.sourcepath"/>
            <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.luckypick"/>
        </javac2>

        <copy todir="${luckypick.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${module.luckypick.basedir}/src">
                <patternset refid="compiler.resources"/>
                <type type="file"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${module.luckypick.basedir}/res">
                <patternset refid="compiler.resources"/>
                <type type="file"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="compile.module.luckypick.tests"
            depends="register.custom.compilers,compile.module.luckypick.production"
            description="compile module LuckyPick; test classes" unless="skip.tests"/>

    <target name="clean.module.luckypick" description="cleanup module">
        <delete dir="${luckypick.output.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${luckypick.testoutput.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init" description="Build initialization">
        <!-- Perform any build initialization in this target -->
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="clean.module.luckypick" description="cleanup all"/>

    <target name="build.modules" depends="init, clean, compile.module.luckypick" description="build all modules"/>

    <target name="all" depends="build.modules" description="build all"/>
</project>
```

ant build output:

[image: ant build output]

Comment: Hi @Altug Ceylan, could you provide your luckypick.xml/build.xml. 
BTW you could update your IntelliJ IDEA to 2018.3.4.

Comment: @hce I added luckypick.xml , thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls. try the following:

```
<project name="luckypick" default="all" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
...
<target name="all" depends="build.modules" description="build all">
   <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
            uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
            classpath=".:path/to/sdk/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>    
</target>
```

Also try to use JDK 8. The Packager is removed from Oracle JDK 11.
See  [here for Details](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343)

> A packaging tool can also help fill gaps left by other technologies
>   such as Java Web Start, which was removed from Oracle’s JDK 11, and
>   pack200, which was deprecated in JDK 11 for removal in a future
>   release. Developers can use jlink to strip the JDK down to the minimal
>   set of modules that are needed, and then use the packaging tool to
>   produce a compressed, installable image that can be deployed to target
>   machines.
>
> To address these requirements previously, a packaging tool called
>   javapackager was distributed with Oracle’s JDK 8. However, it was
>   removed from Oracle’s JDK 11 in connection with the removal of JavaFX.

Comment: on java both  8 and 11 "taskdef" key has a warning that states: "Resource 'com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml' not found in the classpath" and this line:  "xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"  has "URI not registered". On    <delete dir="${artifact.output.luckypick}"/> property 'artifact.output.luckypick' is unknown and on xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"> URI not found. I have changed the xml file accordingly on both java 11 and 8. Only java 8 produces a corrupt jar file. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Could you provide your sourcecode on github or as a zip file?

Comment: https://github.com/AranNomante/luckyPick here it is, beforehand, I would like to thank you  for your time

Comment: @AltuğCeylan Your welcome. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: could you revert to your last edit( It worked for me), I thought it didn't work but  it was because I have been fiddling with vm options, I left the vm options blank and it worked. I could deploy a .msi file that installed the working program.

Comment: Hi @AltuğCeylan, I reverted to my first edit. Glad to hear it helped.

Comment: even though this program is not for commercial use, I credited you in the .rar's (that contains the installer) comment section as the person who made the deployment possible. Many thanks!

Comment: That is very kind of you. It wasn't necessary, but it's good to be appreciated. Thank You.